# Python random.choice([i if len(i) == 9 for i in words]) syntax error on list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Python 2.7

Ubuntu 12.04

I'm trying to turn this:

```
nine = []
for each in word_list:
    if len(each) == 9:
        nine.append(each)
return random.choice(nine)
```

Into this:

```
return random.choice([i if len(i) == 9 for i in words])
```

This however gives me a syntax error, I believe the order is correct so what is causing this to fail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dont have else part, `if` has to be at the end. So change

```
[i if len(i) == 9 for i in words]
```

to

```
[i for i in words if len(i) == 9]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a filter (since that is what you are doing)

```
random.choice(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 9, words))
```

Comment: +1 because even though I don't like the `lambda` syntax in Python, I think it's nice that `filter` very clearly expresses what's happening - the list is being filtered.

Comment: To throw a bone to the "list comprehension is better than functional programming" crowd, this will break on python3.x since filter will start returning an iterable and `random.choice` expects an indexible sequence.

Comment: Can just `list()` the filter.

Answer (score 3):

When you're using a conditional statement/ternary operator, you must supply an `else:` part. Try something like:

```
return random.choice([i if len(i) == 9 else '' for i in words])
```

Of course then you may have the chance of `random.choice()` returning an empty string. If you want the list comprehension to only return `i` *if and only if* the length is 9, then you can put the conditional at the end of the list comprehension, which will *not* require an `else:`:

```
return random.choice([i for i in words if len(i) == 9])
```

Comment: I think he wants to gather only the words with length 9.